# Kinesis to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-kinesis

I am wondering what happens when we have, let's say 200 kinesis shards, read by 100 instances which finally dumps data into Kafka topic with 50 partitions? Because one Kafka partition can be subscribed by only one instance at a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're confusing Kafka producers and consumers. There's no Kafka consumers when the data goes from Kinesis to Kafka.

Therefore, data is partitioned like any other Producer. Kinesis here is more of an implementation detail since this is a standard fan-in design